# An occasional java.lang.NullPointerException while running Java EE applications on GlassFish Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

Running Java EE applications using,

- GlassFish Server 4.1 / Java EE 7
- EclipseLink 2.6.0 having JPA 2.1
- Mojarra 2.3.0-m02
- PrimeFaces 5.2 final
- OmniFaces 2.1 final
- MySQL 5.6.11
- JDK 8u45

There is an occasional `java.lang.NullPointerException` thrown quite less frequently upon redeploying an application which nevertheless, does not cause any harm to the application.

```
Severe:   An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.HttpCodecUtils.parseHost(HttpCodecUtils.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpRequestPacket.doParseHostHeader(HttpRequestPacket.java:723)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpRequestPacket.parseHostHeader(HttpRequestPacket.java:717)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpRequestPacket.serverName(HttpRequestPacket.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.getServerName(Request.java:1246)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getServerName(Request.java:1882)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getServerName(RequestFacade.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.coyote.PECoyoteConnector.requestEndEvent(PECoyoteConnector.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.attributes.Attribute.remove(Attribute.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.afterService(HttpServerFilter.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Where does it come from and why? I neither have a reason behind this exception nor the application appears to be responsible.

Comment: Is this a public server? Do you maintain access logs with IPs and user agents? Have you already determined whether it's more likely to be a human or a bot? The exception suggests that HTTP `Host` header is missing or broken, most likely caused by a hacker probe request to find vulrenable servers (as no one sane webbrowser causes this).

Comment: Nothing like a server either. It is merely running on a local computer for a practice session - not in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue until I created a new user specifically to run GF and installed a recent version of the JDK 1.8 (I'm running linux as my OS)

I created a user: `gfadmin`

Create the new user: `useradd -d /home/gfadmin -g staff -s /bin/bash gfadmin`

Then downloaded the JDK 1.8.0_91 from oracle:
*(get the appropriate tar.gz file for your OS and hardware)*
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Place the tar.gz file in `/home/gfadmin`

gunzip and un-tar the file.  It should create a directory:

```
/home/gfadmin/jdk1.8.0_91
```

Edit the gfadmin users `.bash_profile` file and add these three lines:

```
JAVA_HOME="/home/gfadmin/jdk1.8.0_91"
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME PATH
```

Source the .bash_profile:

```
. ./.bash_profile
```

Confirm that you're using the version of java that you just installed, 1.8.0_91:

```
java -version
```